# Override Chrome Extension Page CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to use the Stylish extension on the Chrome extensions page.

But for some reason it's not working. I've attempted to Google this, but I only get answers about overriding CSS with an extension not overriding the Chrome extension page.

Any ideas why it's not working? Or how I can force it?

I initially tried this to style a specific extension without !important. Then I tried it with !important to force it.

```
#fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe {
    display: none !important;
}
```

And then I tried on a general class, just in case I got the extension id wrong. But still it wouldn't work.

```
.extension-list-item-wrapper {
  display: none !important;    
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Chrome extensions, including Stylish, cannot modify content on `chrome://` URLs.

If you want to apply a style to `chrome://extensions/` (actually, `chrome://extensions-frame`), edit the user stylesheet located at `path/to/chrome profile dir/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`.

This style sheet is applied to **all** pages (including the devtools), so make sure that you choose a sufficiently specific / unique CSS selector.

Comment: I'm looking for official documentation on this and couldn't find one. Do you have links?