# Modify Chrome Extension CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to style a chrome extension using some sort of custom stylesheet, without having to edit the extension?

I have tried using CSS editor extensions, such as StyleBot, and they do not work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653388/override-chrome-extension-page-css) is the exact same as mine, but the only answer provided is no longer applicable, as Chrome 33 removed custom.css support, and as far as I can tell from reading the [the Chromium issue about it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318566), it hasn't been added back in.

So, is there currently a way to do this in Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: how about another extension that does the style changes?

Comment: Currently there's no usable way of doing this.